# How to POST via a link in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I try to POST to the SetLanguage action via a link, but not sure how to finalize the following code:

```
<form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path" method="post" role="form">
    @foreach (var culture in cultures) {
        <div>                
            <a href="?culture=@culture.Name">@culture.Name</a>
        </div>
    }
 </form>
```

Should I use the `form` or there is a direct method to send a POST with `culture : 'EN'` param, by eg?

Does the `@Url.Action(action: "SetLanguage", controller:"Home", values: new { culture = culture.Name }, protocol:"POST")` do the work ?

My Controller code is

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
    );

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Links are GET requests. You cannot post via a link; that is what forms are for. You'd need something like:

```
<form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path" method="post" role="form">
    @foreach (var culture in cultures) {
        <div>                
            <button type="submit" name="culture" value="@culture.Name">
                @culture.Name
            </button>
        </div>
    }
</form>
```

Then, whichever button you click, its value will be posted. If you want it to look like links, you can style the buttons accordingly.

Alternatively, you can keep the links, but you would need to use AJAX to post on click.

Comment: will it work, say 3 buttons all of them with attribute Name?

Comment: Yeah. It's essentially like a radio, only it submits immediately when you click one.

Comment: OK... however, Il'd like to be link, cause already all CSS designed to be a link... is there a way to add hidden and onclick submit?

Answer (score 3):

I would use an action on the links itself using a `GET` method instead of relying on a `POST` method. I use this particular piece of code in my project, and it works like a charm.

```
<a asp-controller="YourController"
 asp-action="SetLanguage"
 asp-route-culture="@culture.Name"
 asp-route-returnUri="@Context.Request.Path">
</a>
```

My Controller code then looks like this:

```
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUri = "")
{
    SetSettings(newCultureName);
    return Redirect(returnUri);
}
```

Comment: does your action have an `[HttpPost]` attribute?

Comment: No attribute in my controller

Comment: so, I tried, it really works, thanks for your help... however it's not a POST ;)

Comment: @NicolasPierre: If you aren't limiting this to `[HttpPost]` then this doesn't address the original question. It's may well be a more elegant way of providing a standard `GET` link to the action, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery :

```
@foreach (var culture in cultures)
{
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:setLanguage('@culture.Name')">@culture.Name</a>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    function setLanguage(culture)
    { 
        $.post("/home/setlanguage", { culture: culture})
            .done(function (data) {
                location.reload();
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's good to have a JavaScript example here to illustrate the AJAX approach. That said, there are a lot cleaner ways of illustrating jQuery event handling which should probably be used if this is going to be treated as a best practice here. For instance, a more common approach might be to apply a `data-culture` attribute for the parameter, and wire up the event using a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a TagHelper that generates form as html and receives as parameters the configurations you want to put. Example with TagHelper:
TagHelper class:

```
 [HtmlTargetElement("HyperLink")]
public class HyperLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    #region Proprietes
    public string AspAction { get; set; }
    public string AspController { get; set; }
    public Method Method { get; set; } = Method.Get;
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Style { get; set; }

    private IDictionary<string, string> _routeValues;

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-all-route-data", DictionaryAttributePrefix = "asp-route-")]
    public IDictionary<string, string> RouteValues
    {
        get => _routeValues ??= new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        set => _routeValues = value;
    }
    #endregion


    #region Injectable

    private readonly IUrlHelper _urlHelper;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="urlHelper"></param>
    public HyperLinkTagHelper(IUrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        _urlHelper = urlHelper;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Render output 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="output"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
        var linkName = (await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent();
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var method = Method.ToString().ToLower();
        var link = _urlHelper.Action(AspAction, AspController);
        builder.AppendFormat("<form method='{0}' role='form' action='{1}'>", method, link);
        foreach (var (key, value) in _routeValues)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='{0}' value='{1}'>", key, value);
        }
        builder.AppendFormat("<input type='submit' value='{0}' class='{1}' style='{2}'/>", linkName, Class, Style);
        builder.Append("</form>");
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<HyperLink asp-action="SendData" asp-controller="Default" method="Post" asp-route-data="test">Send data</HyperLink>
```

Controller:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SendData(string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Method:

```
public enum Method
{
    Get,
    Post,
    Delete,
    Put
}
```

Registration:

```
@addTagHelper HyperLinkTagHelper.TagHelpers.HyperLinkTagHelper, HyperLinkTagHelper
```

[Example on Github](https://github.com/nicolae-lupei/HyperLinkWithMethod)

I did not use it, I came only with an opinion

You can inherit from [AnchorTagHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.anchortaghelper?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and rewrite the Process method